# Logging in to multiple iOS apps with Firebase email link authentication on same Firebase instance

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have two separate apps that run against the same Firebase instance (db). I am adding email link authentication for them. The first one went well. I added the dynamic link domain to use (e.g http://one.page.link), and provided that in the iOS app as associated domain. When the email link is tapped it goes to the 1st app and logs in.

I started adding link authentication to the second app. However, when I send the email link, it references the same domain (http://one.page.link), and hence opens the 1st app on the device when tapped, instead of the second app. I would like it to send the link using a different dynamic domain (e.g. http://two.page.link), so I can associate it for the second app, resulting in the second app opening when it is pressed.

Is it possible to configure the dynamic link domain for the app?
Alternately, is there another way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve it on iOS using a custom scheme to redirect to the right app based on the ibi or ipbi value in the firebase dynamic link.

Firebase still sends the same link. So, no change on server. On the client, if the ibi parameter in the url is another app, redirect to that app using a custom URL scheme to open the app. That app then reads the contents of the url and handles sign in if its for it.